# dint know why the process id is working but, script doesn't exit?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, threadpool, pid

I have been receiving this message when I try to execute a python script. can someone explain me what is this message, I can see the process id still working but  no response from the script.

```
OMP: Info #212: KMP_AFFINITY: decoding x2APIC ids.
OMP: Info #210: KMP_AFFINITY: Affinity capable, using global cpuid leaf 11 info
OMP: Info #154: KMP_AFFINITY: Initial OS proc set respected: 0
OMP: Info #156: KMP_AFFINITY: 1 available OS procs
OMP: Info #157: KMP_AFFINITY: Uniform topology
OMP: Info #159: KMP_AFFINITY: 1 packages x 1 cores/pkg x 1 threads/core (1 total cores)
OMP: Info #214: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc to physical thread map:
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 0 maps to package 0 
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 627 tid 627 thread 0 bound to OS proc set 0
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add example of python script are you trying to exectue.

Comment: It says you are running OpenMP on a system that only has one core.